# ReactJS useCallback not a function of react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional Component which is using the hook useCallback. For the last few days everything was just fine. All worked as it should. Today I start up the app and I have this error:

```
React Hook "useCallback" is called in function "loginPage" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function
```

This makes no sense because it has been fine. For debugging I simply erased all code on the page except that one coed and even just put a useCallback template in its place, but still the same. It is as if it has been removed from react entirely.

I checked my react version and find 16.8.6 also in react-dom.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
import React, {Fragment,useCallback } from 'react';
import { Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone';

const loginPage = (props) => {

    const callbackFunction = useCallback(() => {
        console.log("callback called");
        // Do something with callbackCount ...
        return true;
    }, []);

  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see three problems why the error occurred.

> which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

1. `loginPage` is not a component. `useCallback` is a hook and it needs to be called inside a function component (not a class component) or in another hook (a function whose name starts with "use"). Check out the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions).
2. And also the component name should start with a capital letter, so it should be `LoginPage` for it to be a valid React component.
3. You are not returning anything from your component.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome, mate . I've had the similar problem while learning React. The list in the answer are some implicit requirements/conventions you should probably be familiar with 